# Nullpointer exception Processing 3.0

Tags: processing

When i try to run this code and then press a key I get the following error message: 
please feel free to help me out here

```java
> java.lang.NullPointerException    
at processing.core.PGraphics.image(PGraphics.java:3769)     
at processing.core.PApplet.image(PApplet.java:12176)    
at sketch_161102a.tekenBeginscherm(sketch_161102a.java:36)  
at sketch_161102a.draw(sketch_161102a.java:28)  
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2412)    
at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1540)    
at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

this is the code:

thanks
EDIT:

```
String[] kaart = { 
  "Aclubs.png", 
};

PImage[] kaarten = new PImage [kaart.length];

void setup() {
  kaarten[0] = loadImage("kaart[0]");
  image(kaarten[0],50,50);
}
```

still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still aren't loading your images. You need to call the `loadImage()` function before you try to use the `image()` function.

Start smaller. Start with a single image. Use the code in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html) to get that working:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  img = loadImage("laDefense.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

When you get that working, then you can work on loading an array of images.

In your code, since `kaarten` only has a single index, you would load an image into that index like this:

```
kaarten[0] = loadImage(kaart[0]);
```

Get that working first. Then you can use a `for` loop to load multiple images.

Comment: when i add the line in setup() it tells me it can't find the method for kaarten[0]

Comment: @theArminas4 You still need the declaration of your `kaarten` array at the top of your sketch.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with declaring i thought i did that here: `PImage[] kaarten = new PImage [kaart.length];`

Comment: @theArminas4 Please edit your post to include an updated [mcve].

Comment: i updated the post it's minimal complete and verifable now

Comment: @theArminas4 Please notice that you've put `kaart[0]` inside `" "` quotation marks, making it a `String` value. You need to pass `kaart[0]` which is a `String`, not a `String` value that contains the variable name.